# Color code the columns

Tags: vba, excel

In an excel file, I need to color code a column cell depending upon the number of "Yes" in that Column. If there are  no "Yes" : Red color; one "Yes": Yellow color: 2 or more than 2 "Yes": Green color.

Can this be done by some macro ?

**Update**:

Have made this macro but i am not able to run or debug it as it gives an error of Overflow;
The variable N is taking a value of 32676 even after I have assigned it zero value .

```
Sub testcolor()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim N As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim val As String
i = 7
j = 5
N = 0
MsgBox (N)
For j = 5 To 15
Do While i < 13
val = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value
If val = "Yes" Then N = N + 1
Loop
If N = 0 Then
Range(i + 2, j).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
If N = 1 Then
Range(i + 2, j).Select

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
If N > 1 Then
Range(i + 2, j).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
 End With
 End If

Next j
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes this is quitte easy, could you post an image of what you mean exactly? maybe just a paint image or something

Comment: @Myra Be specific in your question pls. Your last requirement was A to K column cell 7 to 13 coloring based on text "yes"? See appended answer. Assumed those cell are not blank.

Comment: @ZAT:Sorry for confusion . Have uploaded an image. At present i need for column E,F,G,H, I, J, K. (rows: 7 to 12). The row 14 with Status cell should be colored E14,F14,G14 etc..

Comment: @ZAT: In your appended code; I have declared Rngg as Range;however i am getting following error : Object variable or with block variable not set. Also uncommented arr and desCell declaration

Comment: reload this page. copy exactly what I posted under appended answer and after success, do the dim or declaration checking. And comment to answer below, not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (set RGB and ColorIndex accordingly, did not get if you want cell text color or fill color):

```
Sub ConditionalColorColumn()
    count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(arg1:=Range("D:D"), arg2:="yes")
    'MsgBox count
    If count = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    ElseIf count >= 2 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If

End Sub
```

APPENDED: you can try this for multiple columns

```
Sub ConditionalColorMultiColumn()
'Dim arr As Variant
'Dim desCell As Range
arr = Array("E", "F", "G", "H", "I","J","K")

For i = 0 To UBound(arr)

Set rngg = Range(arr(i) & 7 & ":" & arr(i) & 12)
'rngg.Select
Set desCell = Cells(14, arr(i))

Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(arg1:=rngg, arg2:="yes")
'MsgBox count

If Count = 1 Then
desCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
ElseIf Count >= 2 Then
desCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else: desCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

Set desCell = Nothing
Set rngg = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this is by using **Conditional Formatting**.

1. Select the area you wish to format. Looks like it's range **E14:K14** in your book.
2. Click *Home* > *Conditional Formatting* > *New Rule*.
3. In the *New Formatting Rule* dialog box, click "*Use a formula to determine which cells to format*".
4. Under "*Format values where this formula is true*", type the following formula:

---

```
=AND(E14="Yes",COUNTIF(E:E,"Yes")>=2,ROW()>=7,ROW()<=13)
```

---

5. Next, click the "*Format*" button.
6. Now, simply choose the design you wish. Perhaps a colored background is enough.
7. The GREEN formula is done, but you have to repeat these steps for the yellow and red formulas.
8. The yellow formula:

---

```
=AND(E14="Yes",COUNTIF(E:E,"Yes")<2;COUNTIF(E:E,"Yes")>0,ROW()>=7,ROW()<=13)
```

---

9. And the red formula:

---

```
=AND(E14="Yes",COUNTIF(E:E,"Yes")=0,ROW()>=7,ROW()<=13)
```

---

Don't forget to apply your format conditions (green/yellow/red background).

Let me break the GREEN formula down for you:

- **AND()** - All of the conditions in between these () brackets need to be met.
- **E14="Yes"** - The cell has to contain the word "Yes".
- **COUNTIF(E:E,"Yes")>=2** - The column must have 2 or more "Yes".
- **ROW()>=7,ROW()<=13)** - The cell has to be somewhere in between rows 7 to 13.

It's quite easy to change these parameters whenever you need to. And perhaps it's easier than jumping into a big chunk of code. It may look quite difficult using Conditional Formatting with multiple conditions, but once you get a hang of it you won't stop using it.

Comment: I tried using Conditional Formatting but there is no change happening. Also for green where you have clubbed two conditions excel is returning an error . Hence I used them seperately one by one. However there is no change happening; otherwise this is the best method .

Comment: @TALK: Also my selection area(which I want to format) is E14 to K14

Comment: @TALK: I simplified the formulae and it is working. Thanks your tip helped :)

Comment: @Myra: Good. I've updated the formulas. Notice that you can use "ROW()" witch means the row for the current cell. Instead of using "ROW(E14)" as I suggested before. A little bit simpler.